# Alamofire post json and response json

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

i'm try to post a JSON using Swift3 and Alamofire and it work successfully in Postman [Postman screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7m9D.png)
but in code the response is HTML string that means an exception in server
i tried to change encoding from `JsonEncoding.default` to `URLEncoding.default` and it works good but after 3 days the same error when i run the app

```
let url = "http://mattam.net/mobileapp/addOrder"
let par:[String:Any] = ["order_restaurant":8,
                                 "order_type":1,
                                 "order_address":1,
                                 "order_within":"45 mins",
                                 "order_exacttime":"09:00 pm",
                                 "order_total":300,
                                 "order_fees":30,
                                 "order_gtotal":330,
                                 "order_user":38,
                                 "pquantity[10]":3,
                                 "pquantity[9]":1,
                                 "poption[9]":238,
                                 "pextra[10]":"80,81"]



        print(par)


        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: par, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON{
                r in
                if r.result.isSuccess{print("------i______i-----")}
                print(r)
                if let result = r.result.value as? NSDictionary{
                    print(result)}

            }
```

and in PostMan Bulk edit is

```
order_restaurant:8
order_type:1
order_address:1
order_within:45 mins
order_exacttime:09:00 pm
order_total:300
order_fees:30
order_gtotal:330
order_user:38
pquantity[10]:3
pquantity[9]:1
poption[9]:238
pextra[10]:80,81
```

and url is "let url = "http://mattam.net/mobileapp/addOrder""

Comment: If you're getting an error on the server end, is that now fixed?

Comment: no in post man it works good but in app there are an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your using `http` instead of `https` in your app.
The screenshot uses `https` while the url you posted (copied from your code) uses `http`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you need to send some post details to the server as a Json, so here is some code to do that:

```
private func alamoFireAjax(url: String, parameters: Parameters, callback: @escaping (DataResponse<Any>) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON(completionHandler: callback)
}
```

Comment: i edited my question and added url if you read the code it looks good but i don't know were is the problem 
can you try it yourself?

Comment: Looks like that is a server error, here is the error I get when loading the page: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218`

Comment: Than perhaps your code isnt sending the right parameters, or your code on the server doesn't expect a json.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and to solve it I placed the dictionary creation in a method call. You can usually get away with most requests but I found anything larger than 10 rows needed a separate method handler.

```
fileprivate func generateParams() -> [String: Any] {

    var params = [String: Any]()

    params["order_restaurant"] = 8
    params["order_type"] = 1
    params["order_address"] = 1
    params["order_within"] = "45 mins"
    params["order_exacttime"] = "09:00 pm"
    params["order_total"] = 300
    params["order_fees"] = 30
    params["order_gtotal"] = 330
    params["order_user"] = 38
    params["pquantity[10]"] = 3
    params["pquantity[9]"] = 1
    params["poption[9]"] = 238
    params["pextra[10]"] = "80,81"

    return params

}
```